# Return post date in specific format wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am trying to display the post date in a special format in WordPress. I succeeded in doing this but the dates are not corresponding to the posts. It seems like my while loop takes only the first date of the post and applies this to the other posts. Ex: I have 3 posts in a grid (post1, post2, post3), the most recent post is published today 10/feb, the other 2 have different dates. My grid will display the date of the most recent post with all posts. The while loop is in a file that gets called when generating every post.

Here is my code:

```
$check = 1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if ($check == 1) {
    echo "<div class='vc-datewrapper'>";
    echo "<div class='vc-datebox'>";
    echo "<span class='vc-date'>";
        $day = the_time('d');
    echo "</span>";
    echo "<span class='vc-month'>";
        $day2 = the_time('M');
    echo "</span>";
    echo "</div></div></div>";
    $check = 0;
}   
endwhile;
```

The output on my page is : 10 feb / 10 feb / 10 feb. Now my question is how do I get the date from each post specifically and not the most recent of the 3?

The whole code (visual composer template: vc_gitem_post_data.php)

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( '-1' );
}

/**
 * Shortcode attributes
 * @var $atts
 * Shortcode class
 * @var $this WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Gitem_Post_Data
 */

$output = $text = $google_fonts = $font_container = $el_class = $css = $google_fonts_data = $font_container_data = $link_html = '';
extract( $this->getAttributes( $atts ) );

extract( $this->getStyles( $el_class, $css, $google_fonts_data, $font_container_data, $atts ) );

$data_source = $this->getDataSource( $atts );
if ( isset( $atts['link'] ) && '' !== $atts['link'] && 'none' !== $atts['link'] ) {
    $link_html = vc_gitem_create_link( $atts );
}
$use_custom_fonts = isset( $atts['use_custom_fonts'] ) && 'yes' === $atts['use_custom_fonts'];
$settings = get_option( 'wpb_js_google_fonts_subsets' );
$subsets = '';
if ( is_array( $settings ) && ! empty( $settings ) ) {
    $subsets = '&subset=' . implode( ',', $settings );
}
$content = '{{ post_data:' . esc_attr( $data_source ) . ' }}';
if ( ! empty( $link_html ) ) {
    $content = '<' . $link_html . '>' . $content . '</a>';
}
$css_class .= ' vc_gitem-post-data';
if ( $data_source ) {
    $css_class .= ' vc_gitem-post-data-source-' . $data_source;
}
if ( $use_custom_fonts && ! empty( $google_fonts_data ) && isset( $google_fonts_data['values']['font_family'] ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'vc_google_fonts_' . vc_build_safe_css_class( $google_fonts_data['values']['font_family'] ), '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' . $google_fonts_data['values']['font_family'] . $subsets );
}
$output .= '<div class="' . esc_attr( $css_class ) . '" >';
$style = '';
if ( ! empty( $styles ) ) {
    $style = 'style="' . esc_attr( implode( ';', $styles ) ) . '"';
}
$output .= '<' . $font_container_data['values']['tag'] . ' ' . $style . ' >';
$output .= $content;
$output .= '</' . $font_container_data['values']['tag'] . '>';
$output .= '</div>';


$check = 1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if ($check == 1) {
    echo "<div class='vc-datewrapper'>";
//  $categories = get_the_category();
//  if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
//      $vc_cat = esc_html( $categories[0]->name );
//      echo "<div class='" . $vc_cat . "'>";  
//  }
    echo "<div class='vc-datebox'>";
    echo "<span class='vc-date'>";
        get_the_date('d');
    echo "</span>";
    echo "<span class='vc-month'>";
        the_time('M');
    echo "</span>";
    echo "</div></div></div>";
    $check = 0;
}   
endwhile; 

echo $output;
```

Thanks for any clues in advance!

Comment: firstly, can you give us the three dates? and what do you get if you replace $day = the_time('d') only by  the_time('d')

Comment: Well the three dates are : 10 feb / 5 feb / 3 feb. So it's displaying 10 feb 3 times. If I replace only by the_time('d'), it gives the same result.

Comment: can you share the complete code?

Comment: @ArneBanck : use the_time() for getting time, and get_the_date() for date, so replace the_time() by get_the_date()

Comment: If I replace that by get_the_date it's not returning antything @bfahmi EDIT: forgot to echo it, but still the same result displays 10 feb 3 times

Comment: @DevKiran updated the question, this is code of visual composer plugin a template that generates the posts.

Comment: @ArneBanck : for the first one [ echo get_the_date('d'); ] and the second one [echo get_the_date('M'); ]

Comment: @ArneBanck: it's working or not?

Comment: @bfahmi forgot to echo it, but still the same result displays 10 feb 3 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135362/discussion-between-bfahmi-and-arne-banck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by looking for a function that called the date in the Visual Composer wordpress plugin.

It looked like this:

```
function vc_gitem_template_attribute_post_datetime( $value, $data ) {
    /**
     * @var null|Wp_Post $post ;
     */
    extract( array_merge( array(
        'post' => null,
    ), $data ) );

    return get_the_time( 'F j, Y g:i', $post->ID );
}
```

And here you can adjust the display of the date. Closing the question again, thanks for the answers.